# Order By Without Sorting SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a way to order columns together without sorting?

I have the following statement:

```
SELECT Name,Email, MondayHours1 FROM tbl_scheduel
Union All
SELECT Name,Email, MondayHours2 FROM tbl_scheduel
```

Produces:

```
Mike   | Email  |  8:00 to 5:00 |  8:00 to 5:00
Aimee  | Email  | 11:00 to 5:00 | 11:00 to 5:00
Mike   | Email  |  5:30 to 6:00 |  5:00 to 6:00
Aimee  | Email  |  5:30 to 6:00 | 5:00 to 6:00
```

Adding `Order By name` will group them together of course;

```
Aimee  | Email  |  5:30 to 6:00 |  5:00 to 6:00
Aimee  | Email  | 11:00 to 5:00 | 11:00 to 5:00
Mike   | Email  |  8:00 to 5:00 |  8:00 to 5:00
Mike   | Email  |  5:30 to 6:00 |  5:00 to 6:00
```

But how can I order by without sorting? Is this possible, I need mike to stay at the top.

Comment: What do you mean Order without sorting. Order IS Sorting.

Comment: you need just MIKE up on the list and rest of them as ordered?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo What?

Comment: @clamchoda What is your criteria for the order of the names. Why does mike come first?

Comment: you need just MIKE up on the list and rest of them as ordered? @CathalMF

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine the order of the employees?

Comment: @CathaIMF He comes first only because that is the order in which I read in the data. But he needs to come first because his hours are the earliest 8:00 to 5:00.  I will add a secondary sort field

Comment: So really you want to order by start time. And beyond that you want to treat start times as falling between say 6am and 6pm.

Comment: I wonder ... how will you know whether the start time is am or pm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ordering" == "Sorting". The SQL keyword tells the DBMS to perform a sorting operation on the result set. In an alternate universe where the "ORDER BY" clause were instead worded "SORT BY", the underlying operation wouldn't change.

Sorting of results is typically pretty efficiently implemented in major DBMSes, though there is a minimum bound to the complexity of a sort in the general case; if N is the number of expected results, it will take NlogN additional time to perform an ordered query versus an unordered one. This can be made more efficient by indexing; if you're sorting on an index, more often than not the information can be retrieved directly from the data files in that order by traversing the index tree, which requires fewer operations than retrieving and then reordering an out-of-order sequence in memory.

If Mike needs to be at the top, you can `ORDER BY name DESC`, or you can order by a specific field indicating the proper sort order independently of any displayed column. But if you want the results to be in a particular order, you have to tell the DBMS to put them in that order.

Answer (score 0):

Using `Case` statement you can customize the sort in `order by` to get the required data upfront.

```
SELECT Name,
       Email,
       MondayHours1
FROM   tbl_scheduel
UNION ALL
SELECT Name,
       Email,
       MondayHours2
FROM   tbl_scheduel
ORDER  BY CASE
            WHEN name = 'mike' THEN 0
            ELSE 1
          END
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ideal way to go about your problem. It appears you want to sort the Name groups based on the earliest starting time of all the rows within that group. If you're using a reporting tool you may want to consider using it's sorting facilities to handle this part of the problem for you. I've also parsed your hours string by assuming it always includes a colon character and that the start of a day is at 6am. It doesn't look at the minutes because as you can see it's already slightly complicated. If you shared more data there might be an easier way.

```
with hours (Name, Email, Shift) as (
    SELECT Name, Email, MondayHours1 FROM tbl_scheduel
    Union All
    SELECT Name, Email, MondayHours2 FROM tbl_scheduel
)
select Name, Email, Shift
from hours
order by
    min(
        case
            when cast(left(@Shift, charindex(':', @Shift) - 1) as int) < 6
            then cast(left(@Shift, charindex(':', @Shift) - 1) as int) + 12
            else cast(left(@Shift, charindex(':', @Shift) - 1) as int)
        end
    ) over (partition by Name),
    Name,
    case
        when cast(left(@Shift, charindex(':', @Shift) - 1) as int) < 6
        then cast(left(@Shift, charindex(':', @Shift) - 1) as int) + 12
        else cast(left(@Shift, charindex(':', @Shift) - 1) as int)
    end;
```